# Problems with 'git push heroku master' Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: git, heroku, github, ssh-keys, heroku-toolbelt

Ok Let's try this again, I created another account on Heroku.com. I downloaded their software I installed it....I ran these commands In this order in the command prompt this was after I generated a key and tried the same thing on OpenShift.com which I will post the result I got from a test to that below this pictures

[image]

I was first having problems with my ssh key and was able to resolve that by deleting the entire key and recreating it and uploading it back to the server now I'm trying to add by git file to the stack and I checked and I have a Cedar app as shown below

[image]

I would appreciate it if anyone knows what the cause of my problem could be, I done checked all the other posts on this topic google after google, I have been trying to get through this entire process for 3 days now and I'm about to give up. I just wanted a host for my JavaFX webapplets

Answer (score 1):

It's rejecting the `git push` because it's not detecting any code.

It looks like you're pushing an empty git repository.  There's no way Heroku can do anything with an empty repo, so it's responding with an error message "no app detected" - which sounds about right as you haven't given it an app.

Comment: Oh, well I think maybe this isn't what I thought it was....idk maybe I should do more research into this subject but from an article I read I was lead to believe that I basically used sites like this to host my java applications, I guess I need to go do more research into what exactly all this is meant for, I tried to choose an app from their app store but it wanted me to verify my address with a credit card...I'm interested in learning this because I am working my way through college right now for computer engineering...could you perhaps direct me to a good guide?

Comment: I seriously feel dumbed down by all this, I feel like I don't even know what this is for...perhaps I was given the wrong impression, because it seems to complex for simple java apps...I understand that it doesn't just support java but I'm confused now as to what exactly it is for

Comment: anyway to make me feel even stupider I figured out that I could simply host my java app from pretty much any free webhosting site XD I got one thrown up now as a test....for some reason I thought you had to have a special server for putting them up on the web

Comment: btw here is the repository I cloned and was trying to add but apparently there is something that I am missing or I have a totally wrong concept of what I am supposed to be doing https://github.com/John-Conner/Tic_Tac_Toe    and here is a site I hosted the app on last night http://john-conner.uhostfull.com/   Obviously having rendering problems but it works, I will have to figure out why it did that because it doesn't do it from my compiler